# String data still remains? (Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string)

Tags: java

I am trying out to code a simple arithmetic game in Java but I faced an error like: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string`. This happens when I clicked on number buttons and cleared them to enter a new number but it seems that the string still contains the previous number I clicked. (For example, I clicked 5 and deleted it so I could enter 9 instead and now the string seems to register it as 59 instead of just 9.) I used `.setText('')` to clear the text area.

This is my code for when the buttons are pressed:

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("one"))
        {
            answerText.append("1");
            userAnswer = userAnswer + "1";  
        }
        // same code for two, three, four... to nine.
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("enter"))
        {
            int userValue = new Integer(userAnswer);
            if (userValue == rightAnswer)
            {
                score++;
                userAnswer = "";
                generateRandomProblem();      
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Wrong answer! Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
```

The answer variable and delete button is :

```
        answerText = new JTextArea();
        answerText.setEditable(false);

        clearbtn = new JButton("Clear");
        clearbtn.setActionCommand("clear");
        clearAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                answerText.setText("");
            }
        });
```

How do I make sure that my `answerText` is completely clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string

This means that you are trying to parse a string into a number, but the string contains something that cannot be parsed into a number. Java prints the content of the string after the text `For input string`. In this case there's nothing after that text, because the string that you are trying to parse is the empty string - that you set in the text box by calling `answerText.setText("");`

Solution: Check if the string you are trying to parse is empty before you try to parse it into a number. For example:

```
if (e.getActionCommand().equals("enter"))
{
    if (!"".equals(userAnswer)) // Check if userAnswer is not empty
    {
        int userValue = new Integer(userAnswer);
        if (userValue == rightAnswer)
        {
            score++;
            userAnswer = "";
            generateRandomProblem();      
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Wrong answer! Please try again.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter a number before pressing Enter.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that out and I get the ```Wrong answer!``` dialog instead, despite inputing the correct answer.

Comment: What do the variables `userValue` and `rightAnswer` contain when it goes wrong? Try using a debugger or add `System.out.println(...);` statements to find out what the values of the variables are. Where are those variables declared and what is their type?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `userAnswer` doesn't get cleared when `answerText` is cleared. This might cause issues.

The exception you are having is probably being cause because `int userValue = new Integer(userAnswer);` is called at a point where `userAnswer` is empty (because it can't make a number out of nothing).